# Laravel Supervisord DB Deadlock

Tags: mysql, laravel, supervisord

Using Laravel and Supervisord to keep php artisan queue:listen running. For some reason it has run well for a long time and now suddenly I'm getting this error and then the job is restarting

`[2016-02-19 14:49:23] production.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Database\QueryException' with message 'SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction (SQL: update`accounts`set`updated_at`= 2016-02-19 14:49:23,`ReceivableBalance`= 11968.1419330000,`RecoupableIncomeTotal`= 0,`RecoupableExpenseTotal`= 0 where`id`= 74)' in /home/ec2-user/MPWLaravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:555`

...

I read a few things that said I was getting a dealock because too many queue workers were running but I should only have one.

When I run, `ps aux | grep artisan` I get...

`c2-user 12838  0.2  0.6 348288 26200 ? S 19:42   0:01 php artisan queue:listen --timeout=600
ec2-user 12920 76.3  2.0 484132 78212 ? R 19:49   3:47 php artisan queue:work --queue=https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/129423672202/MpwNewProduction --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=3 --tries=0 --env=production`

which suggests two queue workers running? Which may cause the deadlock? Or is that just the one running and then the `queue:listen` is just still checking for new messages?

So lost.

Comment: Were any changes made to the codebase regarding db interaction since the queue was started with supervisor? If yes, does this still occur after restarting supervisord?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm on the most current master branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ended up being a second queue listener running I was unaware of. For anyone who may stumble upon a similar issue.

Comment: Well, I'm facing the same problem but, with different queue listeners listening to different queues other than "default".